# GTMSessionFetcher.h -Multiple Errors after Updating Pod

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

When I update my pods, I constantly get multiple `GTMSessionFetcher.h` errors.

> Duplicate interface definition for class 'GTMSessionFetcherUserDefaultsFactory'
>
> Redefinition of 'GTMSessionFetcherError'
>
> Redefinition of 'GTMSessionFetcherStatus'
>
> Duplicate protocol definition of 'GTMFetcherDecoratorProtocol' is ignored
>
> Duplicate protocol definition of 'GTMSessionFetcherServiceProtocol' is ignored
>
> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'GTMFetcherDecoratorProtocol'; did you mean 'GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol'? ; Reference to 'GTMFetcherDecoratorProtocol' is ambiguous
>
> 'GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol' is deprecated: implement GTMSessionFetcherAuthorizer instead
>
> Duplicate protocol definition of 'GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol' is ignored
>
> No type or protocol named 'GTMSessionFetcherServiceProtocol' ; Reference to 'GTMSessionFetcherServiceProtocol' is ambiguous

I then deleted the pod file, and reinstalled from scratch:

```
$ rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile
$ pod cache clean --all
$ pod init
// reinstalled the same pods
```

And the same errors keep appearing. I also cleaned the project.

One very odd thing that I noticed is my Firebase pod only installs versions `9.6.0` when Firebase is currently on [version 10.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios). It installs 9.6.0 for both updating the pod and freshly installing the pod.

**Any idea what the issue is?**

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ’10.0’

install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'MyAppName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyAppName

#pod 'Firebase' // tried with and without this, same problems
pod 'Firebase/Functions'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Installations'
pod 'Firebase/Database'

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'KeychainSwift'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
pod "SwiftPhoneNumberFormatter"
pod 'ObjectMapper'
pod 'InstantSearchClient', '~> 7.0'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
end

end
```

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - AFNetworking (4.0.1):
    - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 4.0.1)
    - AFNetworking/Reachability (= 4.0.1)
    - AFNetworking/Security (= 4.0.1)
    - AFNetworking/Serialization (= 4.0.1)
    - AFNetworking/UIKit (= 4.0.1)
  - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (4.0.1):
    - AFNetworking/Reachability
    - AFNetworking/Security
    - AFNetworking/Serialization
  - AFNetworking/Reachability (4.0.1)
  - AFNetworking/Security (4.0.1)
  - AFNetworking/Serialization (4.0.1)
  - AFNetworking/UIKit (4.0.1):
    - AFNetworking/NSURLSession
  - AppAuth (1.6.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (= 1.6.0)
    - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (= 1.6.0)
  - AppAuth/Core (1.6.0)
  - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (1.6.0):
    - AppAuth/Core
  - Firebase/Auth (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Core (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Database (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDynamicLinks (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Functions (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFunctions (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Installations (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (~> 9.6.0)
  - Firebase/Storage (9.6.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseStorage (~> 9.6.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 9.6.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 9.6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (9.6.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.7)
  - FirebaseAuthInterop (9.6.0)
  - FirebaseCore (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseCoreInternal (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (9.6.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (< 10.0.0, >= 9.1.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseCoreExtension (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
  - FirebaseCoreInternal (9.6.0):
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (< 10.0.0, >= 9.1.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseDatabase (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
  - FirebaseDynamicLinks (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
  - FirebaseFunctions (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseCoreExtension (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseMessagingInterop (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseSharedSwift (~> 9.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.7)
  - FirebaseInstallations (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseMessaging (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 9.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (< 10.0.0, >= 9.1.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - FirebaseMessagingInterop (9.6.0)
  - FirebaseSharedSwift (9.6.0)
  - FirebaseStorage (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseAppCheckInterop (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseAuthInterop (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseCoreExtension (~> 9.0)
    - FirebaseStorageInternal (~> 9.0)
  - FirebaseStorageInternal (9.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 9.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.7)
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (9.14.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (< 11.0, >= 7.0)
    - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (>= 1.1)
  - GoogleAnalytics (3.20.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (9.6.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (= 9.6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport (9.6.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (= 9.6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport (9.6.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.7)"
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (9.2.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.7)
    - nanopb (< 2.30910.0, >= 2.30908.0)
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleMaps (4.2.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 4.2.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (4.2.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (4.2.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GooglePlaces (4.2.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base (= 4.2.0)
  - GoogleSignIn (7.0.0):
    - AppAuth (~> 1.5)
    - GTMAppAuth (< 3.0, >= 1.3)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 1.1)
  - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (2.0.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.11.0):
    - PromisesObjC (< 3.0, >= 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.11.0)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.11.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMAppAuth (2.0.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (~> 1.6)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 1.5)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (2.3.0)
  - InstantSearchClient (7.0.5)
  - IQKeyboardManagerSwift (6.5.11)
  - KeychainSwift (20.0.0)
  - leveldb-library (1.22.1)
  - nanopb (2.30909.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30909.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30909.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30909.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30909.0)
  - ObjectMapper (4.2.0)
  - PersonalizedAdConsent (1.0.5)
  - PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
  - ReachabilitySwift (5.0.0)
  - SDWebImage (5.15.0):
    - SDWebImage/Core (= 5.15.0)
  - SDWebImage/Core (5.15.0)
  - SVProgressHUD (2.2.5)
  - SwiftPhoneNumberFormatter (1.5)
  - SwiftyJSON (5.0.1)
  - SwiftyStoreKit (0.16.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - AFNetworking
  - Firebase/Auth
  - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Database
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks
  - Firebase/Functions
  - Firebase/Installations
  - Firebase/Messaging
  - Firebase/Storage
  - FirebaseAnalytics
  - FirebaseCrashlytics
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
  - GoogleAnalytics
  - GoogleMaps
  - GooglePlaces
  - GoogleSignIn
  - InstantSearchClient (~> 7.0)
  - IQKeyboardManagerSwift
  - KeychainSwift
  - ObjectMapper
  - PersonalizedAdConsent
  - ReachabilitySwift
  - SDWebImage
  - SVProgressHUD
  - SwiftPhoneNumberFormatter
  - SwiftyJSON
  - SwiftyStoreKit

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - AFNetworking
    - AppAuth
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAppCheckInterop
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseAuthInterop
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreExtension
    - FirebaseCoreInternal
    - FirebaseCrashlytics
    - FirebaseDatabase
    - FirebaseDynamicLinks
    - FirebaseFunctions
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - FirebaseMessagingInterop
    - FirebaseSharedSwift
    - FirebaseStorage
    - FirebaseStorageInternal
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - GoogleAnalytics
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleMaps
    - GooglePlaces
    - GoogleSignIn
    - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform
    - GoogleUtilities
    - GTMAppAuth
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - InstantSearchClient
    - IQKeyboardManagerSwift
    - KeychainSwift
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - ObjectMapper
    - PersonalizedAdConsent
    - PromisesObjC
    - ReachabilitySwift
    - SDWebImage
    - SVProgressHUD
    - SwiftPhoneNumberFormatter
    - SwiftyJSON
    - SwiftyStoreKit

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  AFNetworking: 3bd23...
  AppAuth: 8fca6...
  Firebase: 5ae8...
  FirebaseAnalytics: 89ad...
  FirebaseAppCheckInterop: d5ec...
  FirebaseAuth: e4a5...
  FirebaseAuthInterop: b6cf...
  FirebaseCore: 2082...
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 99a49...
  FirebaseCoreExtension: e834...
  FirebaseCoreInternal: bca7...
  FirebaseCrashlytics: 3210...
  FirebaseDatabase: 3de1...
  FirebaseDynamicLinks: 894e...
  FirebaseFunctions: f9d4...
  FirebaseInstallations: 0a11...
  FirebaseMessaging: a4d7...
  FirebaseMessagingInterop: 34878...
  FirebaseSharedSwift: 2269...
  FirebaseStorage: 1fea...
  FirebaseStorageInternal: 81d8...
  Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK: 4fe6...
  GoogleAnalytics: 01e4...
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 6de2...
  GoogleDataTransport: 1c81...
  GoogleMaps: eb03...
  GooglePlaces: 196a...
  GoogleSignIn: b232...
  GoogleUserMessagingPlatform: 5f8b...
  GoogleUtilities: c2bd...
  GTMAppAuth: 99fb...
  GTMSessionFetcher: 3a63...
  InstantSearchClient: cd4b...
  IQKeyboardManagerSwift: c7955...
  KeychainSwift: 0ce6...
  leveldb-library: 50c7b...
  nanopb: b552...
  ObjectMapper: 1eb4...
  PersonalizedAdConsent: dbeca...
  PromisesObjC: ab77f...
  ReachabilitySwift: 98503...
  SDWebImage: 9bec4...
  SVProgressHUD: 1428a...
  SwiftPhoneNumberFormatter: 0cc91...
  SwiftyJSON: 2f33a...
  SwiftyStoreKit: 6b9c0...

PODFILE CHECKSUM: c039d...

COCOAPODS: 1.11.3
```

Error Pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10726

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from @PaulBeusterien
[here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10726#issuecomment-1408807696) "The CocoaPods installation directory should not be searched recursively for include paths."

Under `User Header Search Paths` I set `Pods/**` `recursively`, and setting it `recursively` was the problem.